# What is this pink flowered plant with 3- and 5-lobed leaves?

Tags: identification

I live in the Pacific North West (Victoria,BC) and these have been in flower for about a week.  They grow to about 18" and from a distance they could be mistaken for geraniums.  Up close the petals don't look like any geranium I've ever seen.  Basal leaves have 5 lobes, those on the flower stems have 3.
[image: First photo is the blooms]

[image: Second is the leaf on the flower stem]

[[image: Third is the basal leaf[3]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be Astrantia major, not sure which variety, there are hundreds, but it might be 'Roma' https://www.amazon.co.uk/Astrantia-major-Perennial-Masterwort-Deciduous/dp/B01BMNW65A. The flowers on yours aren't quite fully out yet, most of the images on line show it fully open, but compare in a day or so as the flowers progress. Certainly the foliage matches.